# Editing "testproject.zip" to stop "UnitTest1.cs" being created

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template

I've been modifying the VS2010 item and project templates so each time we do a "new project" or "new item" we get it created in a format that works for us.  This is all working fine; if we create a new class library we get it with the references we've set up and it doesn't create the "class1.cs" file - that all works.  We've made a similar change to the TestProject.zip file that lives in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Test\1033

Gone through the same process of zipping it back up, copying it over top of the original and refreshing the cache.  However for the test project we can't stop it creating the default "unittest1.cs" file.  All of our other changes to the test project are working fine but we just can't stop it creating the "unittest1.cs" file.  It was never in the template or csproj file originally so I'm not sure what is creating it.

Can anyone help?  What creates the default test file for the test project - I'm wondering if it's a reference to the wizard that is in the template file but have no idea what changes would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Extract `BasicUnitTest.zip` from:

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
   >   10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033
3. Open `BasicUnitTest.vstemplate`
4. Remove `<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">UnitTest.cs</ProjectItem>`
5. Zip `BasicUnitTest.vstemplate` into `BasicUnitTest.zip` (*excluding* `UnitTest.cs`)
6. Go to:

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
   >   10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\1033
7. Delete `UnitTest.cs` and replace `BasicUnitTest.vstemplate` with your modified copy
8. On the next run of Visual Studio you should see the modified UnitTest

Though you can do this for every default template, I recommend creating a new template based on the `BasicUnitTest.zip` instead of overriding the ones shipped with Visual Studio. It's easier, safer and won't be overwritten by future service packs.

Comment: Thanks, I think that seems to do exactly what I want - can I ask how you joined up "basicunittest.zip" to the project to resolve this as I couldn't find the link.   Thanks once again.

Comment: I suppose the link is the GUID between the two: `<Name Package="{52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}" />`