# How does Visual Studio determine which item templates are available in a project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to have the Add->View... context menu item available in a project that starts out as a class library, just as it is available in a project that starts out as an MVC 4 project. I have given the .csproj file a cursory read through, but I don't see anything saying, "This is an MVC project", so how does VS know this?

I have since learnt that VS looks at the ProjectTypeGuids element in the project file, and that I must add the GUID E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47 to the front of this elements value. Maybe my question is clearer now that I can say I'm trying to find out what the association is between these GUIDs and the item templates available in a project.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9438237/147211) help?

Comment: @KMoraz Maybe. The one comment there notes that the project and item templates have `<Name Package="{52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}" />` in common. I will follow that up.